# ERROR - Bad request; check the error message for details

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I created API with spring. When I call that API then show error

Here is the Controller class.

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/dPIUsagePackageInfo"},method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public ResponseEntity<DPIUsagePackageInfoRs> dPIUsagePackageInfo(@RequestBody List<DPIUsagePackageInfoRq> dPIUsagePackageInfoRq){

      //
      DPIUsagePackageInfoRs response = this.ccbsBusiness.dPIUsagePackageInfo(dPIUsagePackageInfoRq);
      return new ResponseEntity(response, response.getStatus());
  }
```

Here is the Request class

```
public class DPIUsagePackageInfoRq {    

    private List<String> srvName;


    public List<String> getSrvName() {
        return srvName;
    }

    public void setSrvName(List<String> srvName) {
        this.srvName = srvName;
    }


}
```

I passed this json body

```
{
    "dPIUsagePackageInfoRq" : {
        "srvName": ["xxx","rrr","rrrrr"]
    }
}
```

But response like this

```
{
    "resultCode": "000400",
    "resultDesc": "ERROR - Bad request; check the error message for details."
}
```

Where is the wrong with my code.Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Do you send a post or get request?

Comment: @Jens request is POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending only one DPIUsagePackageInfoRq instance where you should be sending it in a list. Please try adding "[" and "]" to start and end of your body so that it becomes a list.

The request which you are sending should be as follows:

```
[
    {
        "srvName": ["xxx","rrr","rrrrr"]
    }
]
```

and if you would like to send multiple DPIUsagePackageInfoRq objects, you can use increment the objects like this:

```
[
    {
        "srvName": ["xxx","rrr","rrrrr"]
    },
    {
        "srvName": ["xxx","rrr","rrrtrr"]
    }
]
```

Comment: @ahemetcetin Im newbie for this. can you do what your update with my request body.Please thank you.

Comment: @QOnly I added the body of the json, I tested it and it should be working for you too.

Comment: Can you give green tick to the answer if it worked for you. Thanks.

Comment: @ahemetcetin I removed the List from the controller class . Now it's like (RequestBody DPIUsagePackageInfoRq dPIUsagePackageInfoRq). Then give same error. DO you have any idea. Thanks.

Comment: @QOnly if you removed the list but take only one object, then you should remove "[" and "]. The request must be like this:
{
        "srvName": ["xxx","rrr","rrrrr"]
}